# Should a 3m cable charge speed be significantly different than a 1m cable?

Tags: charging, power

I recently bought a 3m (meter) Apple charging cable and found that it was charging my iPad slower than usual.

I plugged it to a USB tester and found that it charged at ~5v 1A.  By comparison, my 1m cable charged at around 5v 2A.

Is it this normal, should there be that much of a difference?

I'm testing by charging an iPad. The wall adapter is the genuine 12W iPad wall outlet rated at 5.2v at 2.4A. I have a genuine Apple 1m cable and I also bought a 3m and 1m cable third party cable off eBay. They are unbranded.

- Both genuine and non-genuine 1m cables charged my iPad at around 5v 2A.
- The non-genuine third party 3m, cable charged the same iPad at a bit less than 5v 1A.

The cable nor USB tester gets warms up enough to feel, but the wall plug does, so I don't think it will be (hope it won't be) a fire hazard.

Here are some pictures of the USB tester, maybe that will help. First one is a with the 3m cable

[image: 3m charging cable]

This one for the 1m cable
[image: 1m charging cable]

Comment: There's a lot missing here.  Are these charging cables USB-C or something else?  Are they genuine Apple or 3rd party?  If the latter, what's the make/model (a link would be helpful)?  What do you have plugged into the USB tester?  Is it the same device or the tester by itself?  Make/model of the tester?

Comment: Also, for wire (assuming 18/20 AWG) the resistance drop is about 42Ω per Km.  It can't drop that much from 1m to 3m

Comment: Wouldn’t the tester be more suspect than an Apple cable or might you have gotten a counterfeit cable? Not sure what sort of answer you’re looking for without putting a little more specifics on how you are testing or measuring things. High current charging involved signaling and not just a full on pipe of energy.

Comment: The 3m is a third party cable unbranded, I don't think the tester is culprit as the reason I pulled out the tester was because it was charging slower than usual, which reminded me that I had a tester.

Comment: Is the iPad fully or close to being fully charged when you test?  In other words, are you testing both scenarios with the same battery level?

Comment: The chip that is inside the Lightning connector probably limits the power. Here's the same problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4829625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3m (meter) 3rd party cable is the problem here.  There are two possibilities:

- it's for an older iDevice that didn't have or support quick charging (iPods, iPhones, etc.)
- it's a cheap knockoff where the manufacturer didn't supply the correct chip to request higher power delivery

When selecting a 3rd party (non-genuine) Apple accessory, it's always good to go with known brands - I myself prefer Anker or even Amazon basics.

#### Understanding power adapters and cables

There's a lot of misunderstanding in the question about the role cables play in the charging process.  Let's clear some of that up...

- The cable itself, doesn't dictate how much power drawn.  Two cables of similar [AWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) (gauge or *diameter* of the wire) isn't going to draw vastly different amounts of power.  For the inherent resistance of the cable to become a factor in dropping power, we start looking at distances in the kilometer range (a thousand times longer than what you're working with).
- A typical 20 AWG copper cable can support from 4A (multi-core like braided wire) and up to 6A (solid core) of current.  At 2A, you are well within the tolerances and "getting warm to the touch" is perfectly normal.
- There are many differences for the amount of *[current draw](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95874/when-people-talk-about-a-device-drawing-current-what-do-they-mean-why-do-dev)* on a device:

  - **Load** -  an idle computer draws less power than one crunching away displaying video
  - **Charging state** - a fully charged battery draws less power to charge than a depleted one.  Also intelligent chargers go from "rapid charge" to "trickle charge" once a threshold has been reached.
  - **Power Negotiation** - intelligent devices like quality Apple cables or USB 3.1 chargers negotiate the amount of power delivered.

The issue specific to your situation is the last point - power negotiation.  In Apple cables - both Apple branded and high quality 3rd party - there is a chip that negotiates with the power brick how much power to deliver

[image]
<sup>Photo courtesy [Chipworks](https://www.chipworks.com/about-chipworks/overview/blog/inside-apple-lightning-cable)</sup>

If the chip in the cable only requests 1A of power, the power brick will only deliver 1A of power.

Comment: Just to make sure, it is likely that my 3m cable chip, only negotiates 1A of current, instead of 2?

Comment: That’s correct.   It’s probably for an older iDevice that didn’t support quick charging

Comment: I contacted the seller, and they told me the supplier said that there where 3 types of lightning cables that come from China,  3 pin which is not good ,5 pin which is good enough for sale and 8 pin which is original quality. They told me the one I got was probably the 5 pin which resulted in lower current draw. That doesn't sound right to me, I thought that lightning cables had to be  8 pin. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If the cable/cord is built into the pronged outlet plug (i.e. the cable cannot be separated from the outlet plug), the difference could be because the device produces a different output current. If this is the case, check the *plug end* of the cable and look for printed text (it may be small) on the casing. Reading this text should confirm the output voltage/amperage.

However, if your cables are not directly built into the *plug end*, then your cord that is producing fewer amps is probably **dangerous and a fire hazard**!

Why? -- If it is not transmitting close to the same current as your other cable/cord, that means the energy that would have been given to your device's battery is instead being dissipated/lost in the cable, probably as heat. In this case, don't use the cable - it could cause a fire and/or damage your electronic device.

Does the cable heat up? Does the cable have any damaged/exposed/frayed wires?

Comment: So, basically you're saying, nobody should use USB-A/C chargers because the cable is not built into the transformer portion of the adapter?  That's a ton of iPhones, iPods, and iPads that you're claiming all have "fire hazard" chargers included with them.

Comment: Allan : No and I see why you thought that. I have edited my comment to make it more clear.

Comment: The 3m cable  I bought was a USB to lightning cable, and the USB plug side does not have a rating in it.

Comment: I'm puzzled what you mean by "cord that is producing fewer amps"?